# "Removing" a node from a functional linked list

Tags: python, functional-programming, linked-list, immutability

I'm looking for a function that returns a linked list that doesn't contain a specific node.

Here is an example implementation:

```
Nil = None                  # empty node

def cons(head, tail=Nil):
    """ Extends list by inserting new value. """
    return (head, tail)

def head(xs):
    """ Returns the frst element of a list. """
    return xs[0]

def tail(xs):
    """ Returns a list containing all elements except the first. """
    return xs[1]

def is_empty(xs):
    """ Returns True if the list contains zero elements """
    return xs is Nil

def length(xs):
    """                                                                                                                                                                               
    Returns number of elements in a given list. To find the length of a list we need to scan all of its                                                                               
    elements, thus leading to a time complexity of O(n).                                                                                                                              
    """
    if is_empty(xs):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + length(tail(xs))

def concat(xs, ys):
    """ Concatenates two lists. O(n) """
    if is_empty(xs):
        return ys
    else:
        return cons(head(xs), concat(tail(xs), ys))
```

How can a `remove_item` function be implemented?

Comment: Nil = None seriously?

Comment: So?  I think `None` is a good `Nil` value in many cases.  And using `Nil` instead of `None` in the source is more explaining.

Comment: @user2799617 Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def remove_item(xs, value):
    if is_empty(xs):
        return xs
    elif head(xs) == value:
        return tail(xs) # or remove_item(tail(xs), value) to remove all
    else:
        return cons(head(xs), remove_item(tail(xs), value))
```

Note: I am not a Lisp programmer, I haven't necessarily done this the best possible way.

[Edit: I might have misinterpreted what you meant by removing a specific node. If you're starting with a suffix of `xs` rather than a value in `xs` then the principle is the same but the test involving `value` is different]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a tail-recursive solution, you can say:

```
def remove_item(xs, value):
  before_rev, after = split_remove(Nil, xs, value)
  return reverse_append(before_rev, after)

def reverse_append(a, b):
  if is_empty(a):
    return b
  else:
    return reverse_append(tail(a), cons(head(a),b))

def split_remove(before_rev, xs, value):
  if is_empty(xs):
    return (before_rev, xs)
  elif head(xs) == value:
    return (before_rev, tail(xs))
  else:
    return split_remove(cons(head(xs), before_rev), tail(xs), value)
```

Although I don't know if Python does tail-call optimization